# Exponentiate common factors with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, react.js, factors

I've created a function that exponentiates common factors.

I'd like to optimize/simplify it because, as you can see, it's very messy and not very performant

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <View results={ [2, 2, 3, 8, 8, 8, 100] } //only an example
  )
}

function View({ results }) {
  const defaultView = results.reduce((previous, current) => previous.includes(current) ? ((previous[previous.length - 1] = [current, 2]), previous) : previous.some(element => current === element[0]) ? (previous[previous.length - 1][1]++, previous) : [...previous, current], []).map((element, index) =>
    <li key={`${index} : ${element}`}> 
      {
        Array.isArray(element) ? <>{element[0]}<sup>{element[1]}</sup></> : element
      }
    </li>
  )
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the edge cases by uniformly using the format `[data, count]`, rather than special casing the count-of-1 case.  Your reduction will then look like this:

```
arr = [2, 2, 3, 8, 8, 8, 100]

arr.reduce(
  (m, x) => {
    const prev = m[m.length-1]
    return x == prev[0] ? (prev[1]++, m) : (m.push([x, 1]), m)
  },
  [[]]
).slice(1)

// [ [ 2, 2 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 8, 3 ], [ 100, 1 ] ]
```

Now in your view you can branch on "is the count > 1" rather than on "is it an array".

Arguably, the ternary with side-effects inside using the comma operator is too clever, but it seemed like you were going for terseness.  It easy enough to expand that out into a traditional `if` statement though.  Also, you can reformat it into a 1-liner, but I prefer the clearer formatting at the expense of more lines.